# How to loop through dates when in YYYY and MM format in two separate columns?

Tags: python

I am a newbie to Python and learning my way and your help is appreciated.

I am trying to do a simple calculation where I calculate rolling average of last 4 datapoint (fin_ratio) i.e. (x1+x2+x3+x4)/4

Now my dataset is as follows:

I have put a small sample of file (xl format) here for your reference:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/4gjsprvfc31n79g/test_data_python.xlsx/file

1) it has unique firm_id, so the rolling mean should not use data from two different firm_id ( i.e. I can't just calculate the mean and let it go down the rows as it will then use fin_ratio from two different firms where one ends and other firm data starts.

2) How should I use the firm_year and firm_qtr in the for loop in this case.

Thanks for your time and I appreciate any pointers you may have.
Regards

John M.

Comment: Could you create a sample data from your file, with the relevant columns, and place it in a code block together with your question instead?